# typeorm nestjs many to many relationship insert

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am completely confused as to how to make typeorm many to many relationshop work when using list of strings. I already looked at docs and number of solutions but I can't seems to get it working. Creating the group works fine.

**However updating the relationship table `groups_users` doesn't work**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost/api/group' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "groupName": "group-name",
    "users": ['user1', 'user2', 'user2'] // User as strings. NOT ids
}'
```

```
// Groups.service.ts

export class GroupsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
    @InjectRepository(GroupsEntity)
    private readonly groupsRepository: Repository<GroupsEntity>,
    @InjectRepository(UsersEntity)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<UsersEntity>,
  ) {}

  public async createGroup(
    creategroupsdto: CreateGroupsDto,
  ): Promise<InsertResult> {

    // Handle duplicate key error message
    // right now it throws a server error
    const { groupName, users } = creategroupsdto;
    return await this.groupsRepository.insert(new GroupsEntity(groupName, users));
  }
```

```
@Entity('groups')
export class GroupsEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() public readonly Id?: number;
  @Column('varchar', { unique: true }) public readonly groupName: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => UsersEntity, (users) => users.groups, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'groups_users' })
  users: UsersEntity[];

  constructor(
    groupName: string,
    users: UsersEntity[],
  ) {
    this.groupName= groupName;
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

```
export class UsersEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() public readonly Id?: number;
  @Column('varchar', { unique: true }) public readonly name: string;
  @Column('varchar', { length: 2048, nullable: true }) public readonly userKey: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => ClientsEntity, (client) => client.users, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'users_clients' })
  clients: Clients[];

  @ManyToMany((type) => GroupsEntity, (group) => group.Id, { cascade: false })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'groups_users' })
  groups: GroupsEntity[];

  constructor(
    name: string,
    userKey: string,
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.userKey = userKey;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert like that, as `group.users` wants an array of users, and you're feeding it an array of strings. You could do the following (ugly, hypersimplified and using AR to make it more readable IMHO, but it's past 2am and I just want to get the point through)

```
let groupUsers: User[] = [];

for (const username of creategroupsdto.users) {
    const user: User = await yourMethodToFetchAUserByName(username)
    groupUsers.push(user);
}

group.users = groupUsers;
await group.save();
```

Comment: my understand was I'd supply how the relationship is established e.g. I could supply property values. and typeOrm `OneToMany` decorator would describe the relationship e.g. map ids based on the property value (e.g. user/group name as strings) and then it would CRUD the relationship table `groups_users` for me. Why would have a decorator and then also have my own method `yourMethodToFetchAUserByName` ?

Comment: TypeORM is supposed to fetch the related entities only if you supply and identifier. Unfortunately your users' names, even if unique, cannot be considered identifiers by the orm.

Comment: can't I use `@unique` or `@PrimaryColumn()` to define it as an identifier?